# How do you use GAP to identify a group?

Tags: abstract-algebra, gap-system

How do you use GAP to identify the name of a group from its multiplication table? I know that you can define a group from a set of generators, and then look for the group in the set of internal tables:

```gap
gap> g := Group([ (1,2), (1,2,3,4,5) ]);    
Group([ (1,2), (1,2,3,4,5) ])

gap> IdGroup(g);                            
[ 120, 34 ]
```

But how do find out the name of the group `[120, 34]`?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The [StructureDescription](https://www.gap-system.org/Manuals/doc/ref/chap39.html#X87BF1B887C91CA2E) command might do what you need. For example,

```gap
gap> StructureDescription(g);
```

returns "S5" for your example, the symmetric group on five elements. For comparison,

```gap
gap> StructureDescription(SmallGroup(120,35));
```

gives "C2 x A5" and

```gap
gap> StructureDescription(SmallGroup(120,36));
```

gives "S3 x (C5 : C4)".  I don't know at what point these descriptions fall below the level of naming the group, but is this on the track you want?